# text and picture

Tags: graphics

I am using inkscape for my Pictures. These are in Ecplise imported. I don´t know how to find the `\put(....,...)` Input to define the text in the pdf file:

```
\put(???,???){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$C^{\alpha}$}}}%
```

in:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{213.92344656bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.98997011)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{inkscape_01.pdf}}%
    \put(0.82234036,0.24887298){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$C^{\alpha}$}}}%
    \put(0.20053521,0.87303284){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$\sigma_{\mathrm{T}}$}}}%

  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question seems a bit unclear to me. Can you explain it a bit better?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
  \begin{picture}(100,100)(0,0)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=100\unitlength,height=100\unitlength]{example-image-a}}%
    \put(20,20){$C^{\alpha}$}%
    \put(60,60){$\sigma_{\mathrm{T}}$}%
  \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `\begin{picture}(100,100)(0,0)` creates a bounding box of dimension `100 x 100` with its lower left corner has coordinates `(0,0)` and upper right corner has coordinates `(100,100)` and the `unitlength` is 1. Therefore,

```
\put(20,20){$C^{\alpha}$}%
```

puts the `$C^{\alpha}$` at `x=20\unitlength` and `y=20\unitlength`. If you want it at the center then use, `\put(50,50){$C^{\alpha}$}`. Hope it is clear. In your case (100,100) transforms to `(1,0.98997011)` and the second argument is optional and hence `(0,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Harish's answer, this approach lays text atop the image.  However, in this case, it used the `\stackinset` macro from the `stackengine` package.

The MWE shows single as well as nested insets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{Center}{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{example-image-A}}

And here shown nested:

\stackinset{c}{-12mm}{b}{15mm}{$\alpha^2$}{%
\stackinset{r}{2mm}{c}{}{\Longstack[r]{2mm offset from\\ center right}}{%
\stackinset{l}{2mm}{t}{2mm}{2mm offset from upper left}{%
\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{example-image-A}%
}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]